# How do I download a CSV file from a web server to a local machine using HTTP?

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I download a CSV file from a web server to a local machine using HTTP?

Answer (score 4):

Download file using [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx):

```
string url = "urlToFile";
using (var client = new WebClient())
using(var file = File.Create("someFile.ext"))
{
  var bytes = client.DownloadData(uri);
  file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);   
}
```